# I am looking for a smarter way to create this type of name vectors in r:

Tags: r, for-loop, names

I am looking for a smarter way to create this type of name vectors in r (rmarkdown).

I have:

```
# 'mat' is a matrix with 10 columns 
colnames(mat)<-c("Comp 1","Comp 2","Comp 3", "Comp 4", "Comp 5","Comp 6"
                 ,"Comp 7","Comp 8", "Comp 9", "Comp 10")
```

Ideally I would do something with a for loop;

```
for i =1:10
colnames(mat)<- c("comp 'i'")
```

but this doesn't work. How can i do this?

Thanks' in advance!

Comment: Try `paste`: `colnames(mat) <- paste('Comp', 1:10)`.

Comment: Perfect, it works! Thanks'!

Answer (score 0):

1. To use loop:

`mat` as your dataset name

```
for (i in 1:length(colnames(mat))){
  colnames(mat)[i] <- paste0("Comp", i, sep=" ")
}
```

2. You can also use `dplyr::select()` to rename colnames:

   dplyr::select(mat, Comp1 = colname1, Comp2 = colname2,...)