# How to generate, populate and update a new dataframe based on an old dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains patients with history of their diagnosis codes in the past 10 years; something like:

```
Patient_ID      Diagnosis_Codes     Diag_Code_Description

A               1                   1:Hypertension
A               1                   1:Hypertension
A               4                   4:Diabetes

B               3                   3:Depression
B               3                   3:Depression

C               1                   1:Hypertension
C               4                   4:Diabetes
C               4                   4:Diabetes
…               …                   …
```

I want to extract or make a dataframe that has unique rows of Patient_IDs and separated columns for each diagnosis code that contains the frequency of code incidence for each patient, like the following table but I don’t know how to approach and do this task in R:

```
Patient_ID  Diag1_freq  Diag2_freq  Diag3_freq  Diag4_freq  …
A           2           0           0           1           …
B           0           0           2           0           …
C           1           0           0           2           …
…           …           …           …           …           …
```

The real data has almost 60 000 patients and the diagnosis codes range is between 1 and 999; so the result dataframe would have 60 000 rows and 999 columns. The Patient_IDs in real dataset are numerical and not string but I used “A”, “B” and “C” to avoid confusion. I appreciate any help and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `aggregate()` or `dplyr::group_by()%>%summarise()` or there are some functions in data.table you can use as well check out more here [Data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)

Example of using dplyr:

```
a <- group_by(dataframe, Patient_ID)
```

This will aggregate data at unique patient_id level.

```
b <- summarise(a,
             Diag1_freq  = length(Diagnosis_Codes[Diagnosis_Codes==1]),
             Diag2_freq = ...
...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; this works but I want to avoid writing "Diag1freq=" for each column (as it would be around 1000 columns). I think it's better to use the actual diagnosis values (1,2,3,150,...) as column names, instead of "Diag1freq", "Diag2freq", etc. and approach this as a melt/cast problem. I'll change the question a bit and post it again. Thanks again.

Comment: @NimaCaiser take a look at [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436639/i-am-looking-for-a-smarter-way-to-create-this-type-of-name-vectors-in-r/47437101#47437101) where I posted how to use for loop to create column names. You can use that along with my code above to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that uses the diagnosis values to create a new variable, then uses the `cast()` function from the `reshape2` package to cast the data.

```
rawData <- "Patient_ID      Diagnosis_Codes     Diag_Code_Description
  A               1                   1:Hypertension
  A               1                   1:Hypertension
  A               4                   4:Diabetes
  B               3                   3:Depression
  B               3                   3:Depression
  C               1                   1:Hypertension
  C               4                   4:Diabetes
  C               4                   4:Diabetes"

theData <- read.table(textConnection(rawData),header=TRUE)
library(reshape2)
theData$variable <- sprintf("diag%04d",theData$Diagnosis_Codes)
castData <- dcast(theData,Patient_ID ~ variable)
```

The output looks like this.

[image]

regards,

Len